A generalized permutohedron as the sum of the dilatations of the faces of the standard simplex
I am trying to understand the proof of the statement, specifically it refers to a theorem stated by Postnikov in his text on permutohedra. So, this sentence claims the following:
If $\{Y_I \}$ is a colection of no negative parameters for all $I \subseteq [n]:=\{1, \dots, n\}$, we can define the polytope $P_n(\{Y_I \})$ as the sum of Minkowski of dilatations of the faces of standard simplex
$$P_n(\{Y_I \})=\sum_{I \subset [n]} Y_I \Delta_I$$
If we define a collection of parameters $\{Z_I \}$ as the following sum
$$Z_I=\sum_{J \subseteq I} Y_J \quad \forall \emptyset \neq I \subseteq [n]$$
Then $P_n(\{Y_I \})=P_n(\{Z_I \})$
I'm gonna reconstruct the proof, stopping at the parts where I have doubts.
First case: Let $I_{0} \subseteq [n]$, we can represent the points of the plane $\Bbb R^n$ using barycentric coordinates, concretely the parameters $Y_I$. Using this fact, I think we can write:
$$Y_I=\delta(I, I_0)=\begin{cases} 
1 & \text{si } I = I_0 \\
0 & \text{si } I \neq I_0 
\end{cases}
$$
Note that, refer to this convenient definition of the parameters we have that:
$$P_n(\{Y_I \})=\sum_{I \subset [n]} Y_I \Delta_I=\sum_{I \subset [n] \\ I=I_0} Y_I \Delta_I+\sum_{I \subset [n] \\ I \neq I_0} Y_I \Delta_I=\Delta_{I_0}$$
In addition

If $I_0 \subseteq I$ then $Z_I=\sum_{J \subseteq I} Y_J=\sum_{J \subseteq I \\ J=I_0} Y_J+\sum_{J \subseteq I \\ J \neq I_0} Y_J=1$

If If $I \subset I_0$ then $Z_I=\sum_{J \subseteq I} Y_J=\sum_{J \subseteq I \\ J \neq I_0} Y_J=0$


according to the Kronecker delta.
Now, my partial conclusion is $\{Z_I \}=\{0, 1\}$. When $Z_I=0$ it occurs to me that it may be
$$P_n({Z_I})=\{(t_1, \dots, t_n) \in \Bbb R^n: \sum_{i=1}^n t_i=z_{\{1, \dots, n \}}=1, \sum t_i \geq z_{I}=0, \forall I \subseteq \{1, \dots, n \}\}$$
This describes the standard simplex, namely $\Delta_{I_0}$. Here my question is, in the other case when it takes the value of $1$ would it be analogous?
Finally, Postnikov states that the general case is follow from the fact of $P_n (\{Z_I +Z'_I \})=P_n(\{Z_I \})+P_n(\{Z'_I \})$, I understand that the principal reason for this claim is that actually we work in a face $\Delta_{I_0}$, and when we sum all the faces recover the standard simplex, but can I write this sentence? The fact is I don't understand precisely.
I'll appreciate any help that you can give me.

First of all, it's best to give precise citations. You are looking at Proposition 6.3 of "Permutohedra, associahedra, and beyond" by Postnikov (https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0507163). You also misstate the result, because it should be $P_n^y({Y_I})=P_n^z({Z_I})$, where $P_n^y({Y_I})$ is defined as a Minkowski sum of standard simplices like you have here, but $P_n^z({Z_I})$ is defined in a completely different way.

In general I don't think questions of the form "help me understand this paper/proof" are great for MathOverflow. If you're a student, it's better if you can have some kind of mentor/advisor help you read through a paper. MathOverflow questions should be precise and concise.

@SamHopkins You're absolutely right, but I don't have a teacher who masters the subject, so I have to resort to unorthodox means.
